# Table View, Static Cells, changing Cell Height

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I understand that using a dynamic TableView, you can set the Cell Height using...
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

However, if I am using A Static Table View ( not Dynamic), With Sections,  I would like to programmatically set the height of a cell to 0.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//used to set the height of a cell

CGFloat result;
switch(indexPath.section) {

    case 0:
    {
        //How do I get the ROW number in this section?
        result = 44;
        break;
    }

    case 1:
    {
        //this works if I want to set all of the rowels to this height.
        result = 250;
        break;
    }
```

}

The question asked another way, If I have the indexPath.section...  how can I do something like...
indexPath.Section.row?

Comment: indexpath.row gives you the row

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexpath.row` directly. No need to write `indexPath.Section.row`.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, the [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) gets [extra duties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html). It is a bit confusing as Apple has two different pieces of documentation.

As noted in the other answers, you get:

Getting the Section Index

- *section* property

Getting the Index of a Row or Item

- *row* property
- *item* property